# How could I check total free storage capacity left on my system among multiple hdd's?

Tags: 20.04, disk-usage, storage

I have 15 SATA hard drives attached to my computer and having to go through them one by one, writing down the free space and then summing everything up is not ideal.

Is there a command or a combination of commands that could do that? Ideally where I could pass something like `/dev/sd*` since I do not want to include the nvme drives.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I should read man pages more often. It is as simple as

```
df --total -h /dev/sd*
```

Okay I figured out something

```
df --output=avail  /dev/sd* | tail -n +2 | datamash sum 1
```

What this basically does is listing mounted disks and displaying only the available space as output, then using tail for removing the first line which is the column title `Avail` then finally summing the numbers with datamash.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind with the `df` command in order to exclude virtual RAM disk entries such as `/dev`, use the `-x` parameter:

```
df -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs --total -h
```

Another way to do this is with the `lsblk` command

- `-l` output in list format
- `-n` skip the header line
- `-b` print in bytes
- `-o` outputs specified column(s)
- `FSAVAIL` print file-system size available/free

```
lsblk -l -n -b -o FSAVAIL | grep -v ^$ | \
awk '{sum+=$1} END{print sum}' | numfmt --to=iec
```

Use `grep` to exclude empty lines, `awk` to sum the first column, and finally `numfmt` to convert bytes to "human readable" format.